# form.submit() not working in the below code

Tags: javascript, jquery

> The javascript does not submit the form. On clicking the alert is
>   called, even checked with the object and it is not null. But the
>   .submit() method does not submit the form. Stuck here for a long time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("label img").click(function(){
             alert("11");
            $("#" + $(this).parents("label").attr("for")).click();
               });
        $("input").change(uploadForm);
 });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadForm(){
    alert("1");
    document.getElementById('UploadFileFormId').submit();
}
</script>

<form id="UploadFileFormId" action="UploadFile" method="post"
                enctype="multipart/form-data"
                 style="width: 40px">
                 <label for="UploadFileId">
                 <img src="images/button_up_lo.png"
               onmouseover="this.src='images/button_up_hi.png'"
               onmouseout="this.src='images/button_up_lo.png'" />
                 </label>
                <span id="uploadSpanId" class="hidden">
                  <input type="file" 
                 name="UploadFileName"
                 id="UploadFileId"/>
                 <button type= "submit" id="uploadButtonId" name= "uploadButton" ></button> 
                  </span>
           </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `<input type="submit">`
2. Use `$('#uploadButtonId').submit();` since you are using jQuery.
3. Element ID is case sensitive (`uploadButtonId` vs `UploadFileFormId`)

Comment: Make sure you are using jQuery 1.x as 2.x does not support IE7.

Answer (score 0):

The uploadForm function, which will submit the form, will execute only when the value of the  control changes. Is that what you are expecting?

Note that, in this scenario, if you select a file, then select the same file again, no onchange event will fire.

Comment: i want to submit the form as soon as i select the file to upload

Comment: Your code does work. I've just tested. If I select a file, the form is immediately submitted. Check the Network tab in your console. :)

Comment: but when i do it there is nothing written in the console. Can you please help what can be the issue.

Comment: If you try this fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/kieranpotts/34pxvqs6/ -- and select something to upload, immediately after you'll get the '1' alert and then you will see that the form is submitted. It outputs {"error": "Please use POST request"} only because the form is submitted to jsfiddle.net and that is the response from the submission.

Comment: sorry i missed out to say. it works fine in IE 9 and above but i want it to work in IE 7. it is not working. Thanks for your help. Anyways i have found a different way to do it. :)